Delete a specific value from one column and Rename another Value in Excel using office script
I need help on an ExcelScript where I need the Column J filter then
Delete the entire Row in column J with the value "Canceled"
Renamed any value in column J with "In Progress" to "Assigned"
Renamed any value in column J with "Pending" to Assigned
Renamed any value in column J with "Closed" to Resolved
Can anyone assist me on this?
Thanks
I tried filtering then deleted based on Range
your textDelete range 40:90 on selectedSheet
selectedSheet.getRange("40:90").delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
your text Clear auto filter on selectedSheet
selectedSheet.getAutoFilter().clearCriteria();
your textSet range J2 on selectedSheet
selectedSheet.getRange("J2").setValue("Resolved");
your text Auto fill range
selectedSheet.getRange("J2").autoFill("J2:J103", ExcelScript.AutoFillType.fillDefault);

Because you want to rename or delete rows with specific values, you'll either need to loop through each row of your data to check the value of column J, or apply a filter and then rename or delete the visible rows. These answers might help as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73755902/officescripts-to-delete-visible-rows-after-filtering and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71472284/iterate-over-a-range-fast-in-excelscript-for-web

Load data into an array, write output to sheet after replacing.
Microsoft documentation:

ExcelScript.Range interface getResizedRange()


ExcelScript.Range interface getUsedRange()

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const dataSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    const dataRange = dataSheet.getUsedRange(true);
    // load data
    const dataVals = dataRange.getTexts();
    let outVals: [] = [];
    const colIndex = 9; // Col J
    let delRowsCnt = 0; // rows count
    // loop through rows
    dataVals.forEach(row =>{
        switch (row[colIndex]){
            // replace the values
            case "In Progress":
                row[colIndex] = "Assigned";
                break;
            case "Pending":
                row[colIndex] = "Assigned";
                break;
            case "Closed":
                row[colIndex] = "Resolved";
                break;              
            case "Canceled":
                row[colIndex] = "$DEL$";
                break;
        }
        if (row[colIndex] === "$DEL$") {
            delRowsCnt--; // remove "Canceled"
        } else {
            outVals.push(row); // store the output row
        } 
    })
    // console.log(outVals);
    // clear table
    dataRange.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
    // write output to sheet
    dataRange.getResizedRange(delRowsCnt,0).setValues(outVals);
}



Update:

Question: I used the above code and it filtered for column J but for some reason my formulas in column E: H changed any reason that could have happened


Answer: setValues overwrites formulas in the table.

The script has been updated as follows:

First, remove the rows marked as Canceled.
Apply the replacement rules only to Column J to ensure formulas in the rest of the table remain intact.

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const dataSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    const dataRange = dataSheet.getUsedRange(true);
    const delTag = "Canceled"
    const colIndex = 9; // Col J
    // remove Cancelled rows
    dataSheet.getAutoFilter().apply(dataSheet.getCell(0, colIndex));
    dataSheet.getAutoFilter().apply(dataSheet.getAutoFilter().getRange(),
        colIndex, {
        filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.values, values: [delTag]
    });
    const visRng = dataRange.getOffsetRange(1, 0).getResizedRange(-1, 0).getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.visible);
    if (visRng) {
        const visAreas = visRng.getAreas().reverse();
        let visRngRefs: string[] = [];
        visAreas.forEach(x => {
            visRngRefs.push(x.getAddress());
        })
        visRngRefs.forEach(x => {
            dataSheet.getRange(x).getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
        })
    }
    dataSheet.getAutoFilter().clearCriteria();
    // load data of Col J
    const dataVals = dataRange.getColumn(colIndex).getTexts();
    // loop through rows
    dataVals.forEach(row => {
        switch (row[0]) {
            // replace the values
            case "In Progress":
                row[0] = "Assigned";
                break;
            case "Pending":
                row[0] = "Assigned";
                break;
            case "Closed":
                row[0] = "Resolved";
                break;
        }
    })
    // write output to sheet
    dataRange.getColumn(colIndex).setValues(dataVals);
}


Thank you for your response, however, I used the above code and it filtered for column J but for some reason my formulas in column E: H changed any reason that could have happened.

setValues overwrites formulas in the table. I've updated the code.
